# Is it possible to download ALL Case Attachments as 1 file?

Tags: attachment

Our cases have most often 3-5 files attached.

On the Case page, I can see the files listed.

Is there a way to download ALL attachments together? With out the need to click on each of them?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean as 1 file. If you want to retrieve a list of attachments on a Case, you can simply query the Attachment object, like, List<Attachment> attlist = [select id, body from attachment where parentid = 'CaseId'];

Comment: Try combining a JS query (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#REQUIRESCRIPT , GETRECORDIDS etc samples for AJAX toolkit) with something like http://biesiad.github.com/multiDownload/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you ok using an AppExchange app to address your requirements? if yes, then there's a paid app available on AppExchange **Mass File Download**, its perfect solution to mass-download files/attachments related to a record or multiple records in just 1-2 clicks.

Check out app @ https://sforce.co/34thF8U (AppExchange URL)

Answer (score 1):

You can export all notes and attachments using open-source sfdx-hardis plugin command

- First, define a files export

`sfdx hardis:org:configure:files`

When prompted for SOQL request, you can input `SELECT Id,Name FROM Case`

- Then, run the files export

`sfdx hardis:org:files:export`

More details in this [article](https://nicolas.vuillamy.fr/how-to-mass-download-notes-and-attachments-files-from-a-salesforce-org-83a028824afd)

[image]

*Disclaimer: My company authors sfdx-hardis plugin*